# Tab selector not working on previous tab click when swipe on viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm following [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/#comment-7721) example..

I'm having one issue, when I swipe on `ViewPager`  respective `fragment` appear but when I swipe from from left to right or  right  to left **and select previous Tab** the Tab indicator appear on new selected Tab but respective `fragment` not appear on `ViewPager`.
Please help me, where I'm getting wrong?

Comment: add some images to clarify your question e.g how it looks before and after

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I have 4 tabs in a TabLayout, setup with a ViewPager. Let's say I'm on tab 0. If I swipe right, I go to tab 1. If I swipe left I go back to tab 0. Everything works, tab layout switches, viewpager shows the correct fragment. The problem is here: I'm on tab 0. If I SWIPE to tab 1, it works, but if I then CLICK tab 0, the tab layout "tabIndicator" will go to tab 0, but the viewpager will not change the fragment, and tab 1 title will stay highlighted. It's fixed immediately by clicking or swiping away.

Comment: FYI i'm using TabLayout and ViewPager with setupWithViewPager() method

Comment: Which AppCompat lib version are you guys using? New widgets are notoriously buggy in this lib, so I recommend first trying this scenario out with the newest one (currently 23.0.0) in case you haven't checked that yet.

Comment: Yeah it was a bug in the widget: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183123

Comment: use track the fragment and use a direct call on tablayout to select it

Comment: update your support library to 23.0.1 .. bug is solved ...
Read this section **Changes for Design Support library** in http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It was bug in support lib 23.0.0 but it is solved in 23.0.1.** First of all update your **suppory library**  using SDK manager from the extras section.
and write the following line in app gradle file.

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`

for your reference

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html
and read the **Changes for Design Support library** in Android Support Library, revision 23.0.1 section

Comment: Thanks Man, you solved my issue on which I spent my 1 day :)

Comment: @Moinkhan I am Facing the Same Issue. I am using support library 24.0.0 and also tried the support library 24.1.1

Comment: This issue is not fixed as of mid 2016

Answer (score 4):

This is what i use and works fine.

Adapter:

```
    public class SCFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context mContext;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public SCFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.mFragmentManager = fm;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    // Return the correct Fragment based on index
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Return the tab title to SlidingTabLayout
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }


    public Fragment getActiveFragment(ViewPager container, int position) {
        String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), position);
        return  mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
    }

    private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
public class SCWelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        SCWelcomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        SCSyncFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        SCRegisterFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        SCConfirmationFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private static final String TAG = SCWelcomeActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ViewPager viewPager = null;
    private TabLayout tabLayout = null;
    private Toolbar toolbar = null;
    private SCFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scwelcome);

        // Layout manager that allows the user to flip through the pages
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        // Initialize the Sliding Tab Layout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

        // Connect the viewPager with the sliding tab layout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        adapter = new SCFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), SCWelcomeActivity.this);
        adapter.addFragment(SCWelcomeFragment.newInstance(), getString(R.string.title_tab1));
        adapter.addFragment(SCSyncFragment.newInstance(), getString(R.string.title_tab2));
        adapter.addFragment(SCRegisterFragment.newInstance(), getString(R.string.title_tab3));
        adapter.addFragment(SCConfirmationFragment.newInstance(), getString(R.string.title_tab4));


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Fragment Example :

```
    public class SCWelcomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static SCWelcomeFragment newInstance() {
        SCWelcomeFragment fragment = new SCWelcomeFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public SCWelcomeFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scwelcome, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please try to implement the adapter as i do. Pay close attention that in mine Adapter all instances are saved in the

```
private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your case you are always returning a new instance. So that's why a set the setOffscreenPageLimit(4). to 4 so they are kept in memory as well.

Answer (score 4):

In your activity, after find Views by Id, you should "config" your ViewPager and TabLayout. Some necessary features maybe: "**addOnPageChangeListener**" for ViewPager and "**setOnTabSelectedListener**" for your TabLayout like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int numOfPages = 4; //viewpager has 4 pages
private final String[] pageTitle = {"Food", "Movie", "Shopping", "Travel"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPages; i++) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(pageTitle[i]));
    }

    //set gravity for tab bar
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), numOfPages);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
}

private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager pager) {
    return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    };
}
```

I have a tutorial post about this and it works well! There is no error like yours.
Hope it help:
http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/08/android-material-design-viewpager-with.html

Comment: Awesome tutorial. It makes sense. Thanks for the answer. This should be the upvoted answer

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me AS of end of **2016** the **bug still exists in design support library 24+**. 
**I was able to fix this issue by wrapping the tab layout inside a

co-ordinator layout**

Comment: spent hrs.. this fixed the issue.. and yes support library 24+ issue still exists..

Answer (score 0):

I have more shorter variant to fix this bug (android support design lib v.23.0.0):

```
...
//initialize views
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.clearOnPageChangeListeners();
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new WorkaroundTabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
...
```

And class WorkaroundTabLayoutOnPageChangeListener:

```
public class WorkaroundTabLayoutOnPageChangeListener extends TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener {
    private final WeakReference<TabLayout> mTabLayoutRef;

    public WorkaroundTabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout tabLayout) {
        super(tabLayout);
        this.mTabLayoutRef = new WeakReference<>(tabLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(position);
        final TabLayout tabLayout = mTabLayoutRef.get();
        if (tabLayout != null) {
            final TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
            if (tab != null) {
                tab.select();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using support library version 23.0.0. There was an issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183123 which looks similar to yours. If that is the case indeed, update your support library version to 23.0.1. This issue has been fixed.